# How to snap to the values on a WPF slider, but only show a tick for some of them

Tags: wpf, slider

I have a WPF slider whose minimum value = 0 and maximum value = 50.  I want to show ticks at an interval of 5, but have the slider snap at an interval of 1.   Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10):

The property `Interval` does not affect this behaviour.

Use this:

```
<Slider TickFrequency="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: This does not work. It is not possible to snap at another frequency then 5 now.

Answer (score 6):

```
<Slider TickPlacement="TopLeft" Minimum="0" Maximum="50" TickFrequency="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="False" SmallChange="1" />
```

Disable snapping to ticks with `IsSnapToTickEnabled="False"` and set `SmallChange="1"`.

SmallChange determines the increment when dragging the thumb or pressing the arrow keys.  You can also control the increment when the user clicks on the slider (not on the thumb).  To make the thumb jump, use `LargeChange="10"` to jump 10 units.  To make the slider move to where the user clicked, use `IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"`.  Note, IsMoveToPointEnabled will place the thumb at the nearest SmallChange increment.

Comment: `SmallChange` does actually not affect the dragging of the thumb at all. So this solution does not work.

Answer (score 5):

The normal WPF `Slider` can only draw all tick marks or none at all.
To work around this limitation you can either create your own `Slider` or you can use a trick: Disable the `Slider`'s `TickBar` and draw your own.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TickBar Maximum="{Binding Path=Maximum, ElementName=MySlider}" 
        Minimum="{Binding Path=Minimum, ElementName=MySlider}" TickFrequency="5" Height="4"
        Fill="Black" ReservedSpace="11" />
    <Slider Name="MySlider" Maximum="50" TickPlacement="None" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

`ReservedSpace` is the combined space to the left and right of the outer most ticks, which is exactly the same as the `Thumb`'s width. It is usually 11 pixel. If you use an unusual theme or messed around with it in another way, you have to adjust it in your new `TickBar` as well.

This solution has one disadvantage: The `Thumb` will not be pointy, because the `Slider` thinks, that he has no tick marks. If you want the `Thumb` to be pointy, you have to trick the `Slider` by giving him a `TickBar` and then collapse it later:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TickBar Maximum="{Binding Path=Maximum, ElementName=MySlider2}" 
        Minimum="{Binding Path=Minimum, ElementName=MySlider2}" TickFrequency="5"
        Height="4" Fill="Black" ReservedSpace="11" />
    <Slider Name="MySlider2" Maximum="50" TickPlacement="TopLeft"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And then in your `Window`'s constructor (after `InitializeComponent()`):

```
this.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
{
    var sliderTickBar = (MySlider2.Template.FindName("TopTick", MySlider2) as 
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TickBar);
    sliderTickBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same issue by displaying only the ticks I wanted by setting the Ticks property, setting IsSnapToTickEnabled to false and using rounding in the binding of the slider value. In my example I want to show slider for 0 to 100%, display ticks in 5% increments and snap step to 1%.

The XAML:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
    TickPlacement="BottomRight" Ticks="{Binding PercentTicks}" 
    TickFrequency="1" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="5"
    Value="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}}" />
```

The view model:

```
    public double MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty = Math.Round(value, 2);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

myProperty has value from 0 to 1, so rounding to 2 digits gives exactly 1% step!
Setting the ticks to 5% increments is done in the view model's constructor:

```
var ticks = new DoubleCollection();
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=5)
{
    ticks.Add(i);
}
PercentTicks = ticks;
```